# Setup for evaluating $\iint_R y^2dA$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

$\iint_R y^2dA$, where D is the triangular region with vertices $(0,1)$, $(1,2)$, $(4,1)$.

I was trying to do this problem, and ended up with the wrong answer, $\frac{28}{13}$, instead of the correct answer of $\frac{11}{3}$. I checked my integrations on symbolab and those where coming out right, so it seems like maybe my bounds for the integrals were wrong. I got $D={(x,y)| 0<=x<=4,1<=y<=2}$ And integrated with respect to $x$, and then $y$. Is that correct? I did I figure those wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's convert the double integral to an iterated integral with integration order $dxdy$, since the region is horizontally simple.

$R$ is bounded above by the line $x=7-3y$ and below by $x=y-1$ from $y=1$ to $y=2$. Thus the integral becomes:

$$\iint_R y^2dA=\int_1^2 \int_{y-1}^{7-3y}y^2dxdy=\int_1^2y^2x\Big{|}_{y-1}^{7-3y}dy=\int_1^28y^2-4y^3dy.$$

I trust that you can take it from here? If not, please tell me.

Comment: How did you get the $7-3y$ and $y-1$ for x?

Comment: I found the lines which represent the vertices of the triangles by normal methods. That is, I wrote the equation of the line which connects $(0,1)$ and $(1,2)$ and the equation of the line which connects $(1,2)$ and $(4,1)$. Then, I solved those for $x$, because that is what I choose to integrate w.r.t first.